# Salesforce : How to prevent 'upsert' (executed from an apex Job) of a record, if the record has a checkbox field which is marked false?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

Salesforce question :

We have to update the accounts from a schedulable Job. New records inserting are no problem, but existing records should only be updated if a particular checkbox field is set to true on that (otherwise not to be updated). Also since we know that the apex code runs from a system context.

I am looking for a way which DOES NOT involve pulling the record from the code by searching using the Id and then checking that field value before upserting.

Thank you for helping.

## Code

```
List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>(accountsToUpdate);           
upsert accountList MY_COMPOSITE_KEY__c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a validation rule simply has `Your_Checkbox__c` as error condition. Or make a `before insert, before update` trigger on Account (if you don't have one already) that would inspect all records in `trigger.new` and call [`addError()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) on them. Validation rule is slightly preferred because it's just config, no code.

The problem with either is that it will cause your whole transaction to die. If your batch updates 200 accounts and one of them has this checkbox - this fail will block updating them all. This is done to ensure system's state is stable (read up about "atomic operations" or "ACID"), you wouldn't want data that's halfway updated...

So probably you'll have to mitigate that by calling [`Database.upsert(accountsToUpdate, External_ID__c, false);`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_methods_system_database) so it saves what it can and doesn't throw exceptions...